# Django application fails when hosted on Apache but works fine on Dev server

Tags: python, django, caching

My Django based application is performing following steps

1. Read million of records from XLS and put the data in cache

   cache.set( (str(run)+"trn_data"),files['inp_data'],3600 )
2. Data stored in cache is optimized and stored again in cache

   cache.set( (str(run)+"tier"),tier,3600 )}
3. Data is fetched from cache and put into database.

   tier = cache.get( (str(runid)+"tier"))

The issue I am facing is everything is working fine on Django Dev server but as soon as I hosted the application on Apache( mod_wsgi and apache) the cache is shown as empty(At step 3)

P.S. I am using Local Mem Cache in my application

Comment: What is `cache`? If it is a static property you might be having problems with multiple processes.

Answer (score 1):

The local memory cache is per-process. See the warning [in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/cache/#local-memory-caching) (emphasis mine):

> Note that each process will have its own private cache instance, which means **no cross-process caching is possible**. This obviously also means the local memory cache isn’t particularly memory-efficient, so **it’s probably not a good choice for production environments**. It’s nice for development.

For production, I recommend you use a different cache backend, for example [Memcached](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/cache/#memcached)